# How can I throw an exception in a scanner?

Tags: java

I am trying to do an exception in java with the input integers must be equal to four digits and cannot be non-integer value. After that I am trying to sum the integers and comes to the result.

Here are my codes and do i need to use array to change the scanner method to numbers? Thanks

```
    int id;int sum = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter four-digit integer value:");

    id = scanner.nextInt();

    try
    {
     System.out.println("Your entered four-digit interger is:"+id);
    }
    catch(Exception t)
    {
        System.out.println(" Integers cannot be non-integer value and cannot enters more or fewer than four digits.");
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println` won't throw any exception, `try catch` is useless here. Wrap it around `.nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your expected behavior:

```
        int id;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter four-digit integer value:");

        String num = scanner.nextLine();

        try {
            if(num.length() != 4) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid input");
            }
            id = Integer.parseInt(num);
            System.out.println("Your entered four-digit interger is:" + id);
        } catch (Exception t) {
            System.out.println(" Integers cannot be non-integer value and cannot enters more or fewer than four digits.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Code Example :** exception in java with the input integers must be equal
>   to four digits and cannot be non-integer value. [(Execution)](http://jdoodle.com/a/o7S)

```
public class ScannerInt {

    private Scanner scanner;

    ScannerInt() throws InvalidInputException {
        int id;

        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter four-digit integer value:");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) // only take integer value
            scanner.next();

        id = scanner.nextInt();

        if (String.valueOf(id).length() == 4) // check if number is of length 4
            System.out.println("Your entered four-digit interger is:" + id);
        else
            throw new InvalidInputException("My custom exception : Not  a valid input"); // throwing my own exception

    }

    // my custom exception
    class InvalidInputException extends Exception {
        InvalidInputException(String s) {
            super(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ScannerInt();
        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

1. Here we are only checking input using *scanner.hasNextInt(*)

   - Returns true if and only if this scanner's next token is a valid int value
2. Then we are checking the length to be 4 only : *String.valueOf(id).length() == 4*

If the above condition is not true then we are raising an [custom exception](https://www.javatpoint.com/custom-exception). You can also simply print a message to console.

**Output 1: Valid input**

[image]

**Output 2: only take integer input**

[image]

**Output 3: Throw custom exception**

[image]

> UPDATE: answer to your comment regarding

**" How can i get the output "The entered values cannot be non-integers " when it catch the exception like "#123,1a2b, @34!, "**  [(Execute)](http://jdoodle.com/a/o9T)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerInt {

    private Scanner scanner;

    ScannerInt() throws InvalidInputException {
        int id;

        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter four-digit integer value:");

        if (!scanner.hasNextInt()) // check if non-integer value exist
            throw new InvalidInputException("The entered values cannot be non-integers");

        id = scanner.nextInt();

        if (String.valueOf(id).length() != 4) // check if length is not 4
            throw new InvalidInputException("The entered values can only be of length 4");
        else {
            System.out.println("Your entered four-digit interger is:" + id); // if everything is fine then print the
                                                                                // value

        }

    }

    // my custom exception
    class InvalidInputException extends Exception {
        InvalidInputException(String s) {
            super(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ScannerInt();
        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can i get the output "The entered values cannot be non-integers " when it catch the exception like "#123,1a2b, @34!, im31"

Comment: Hi @Chris.Wong, I have added an update to the answer kindly check the same for your  query.  [run](https://jdoodle.com/a/o9T)